# $Alt(T)=0$ if $T$ is a symmetric tensor

Tags: tensors, multilinear-algebra

Question is to prove that $Alt(T)=0$ if $T$ is a symmetric tensor.

We have $$Alt(T)=\sum_{\sigma}sgn(\sigma)T^{\sigma}$$
As $T$ is symmetric we have $T^{\sigma}=T$ for all $\sigma$.
So, we have $$Alt(T)=\sum_{\sigma}sgn(\sigma)T=T\sum_{\sigma}sgn(\sigma)$$
As no of odd permutations is same as that of no of odd permutations we have
$\sum_{\sigma}sgn(\sigma)=0$ thus, $Alt(G)=0$.

Now, another question is, does the converse hold?

Suppose  $Alt(T)=0$ do we have that $T$ is a symmetric tensor?

I see that this is true for $2$ tensor. Suppose $T$ is a $2$ tensor then,

$0=Alt(T)=sgn(1)T+sgn(1~2)T=T-T^{\sigma}$  implies that $T=T^{\sigma}$.
Thus, $T$ is a symmetric tensor.

I am sure this is true for all $k$ tensors but i am unable to prove.

Do i have to go by contradiction or what... I am not able to guess some path..

Please provide some hints..

Comment: Careful: This is false for $1$-tensors (and $0$-tensors).

Comment: I think you have misstated the converse. You mean "If $Alt(T) = 0$, then $T$ is symmetric", right? (This is false for $k$-tensors with $k \geq 3$.)

Comment: @darijgrinberg : Yes Yes... That was a typo... Thanks for pointing it out :)

Comment: @darijgrinberg : I would be thankful if you can tell me why this is not true for k- tensors with $k\geq 3$.

Comment: @darijgrinberg : Your help is necessary here.. please suggest some hints..

Comment: Over a $2$-dimensional vector space with basis $\left(e_1,e_2\right)$, the $k$-tensor $T := e_1 \otimes e_2 \otimes \underbrace{e_1 \otimes e_1 \otimes \cdots \otimes e_1}_{k-2\text{ factors}} - e_2 \otimes e_1 \otimes \underbrace{e_1 \otimes e_1 \otimes \cdots \otimes e_1}_{k-2\text{ factors}}$ has $Alt(T) = 0$, but $T$ is not symmetric.

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik I was influenced by the post I linked, you're right. At least my edits have got your post some attention :D

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik That was a **mutual** feeling you know.. :D

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik: What do you mean by "where did we get this tensor product"? It belongs to $V^{\otimes k}$, where $V$ is our vector space.

Comment: @darijgrinberg I am little bit confused... We need $T : V^k \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.. So, what we need image in $\mathbb{R}$.. right?

Comment: Your tensors are different from my tensors then. To translate into your tensors, replace $e_1$ and $e_2$ by the corresponding elements $e^*_1$ and $e^*_2$ of the dual basis, and interpret $\otimes$ as the tensor product of maps (i.e., read $f_1\otimes f_2\otimes \cdots\otimes f_k$ as the multilinear map sending every $\left(v_1,v_2,\ldots,v_k\right)\in V^k$ to $\prod_i f_i\left(v_i\right)$).

Comment: @darijgrinberg :  We have vector space of dimension $2$ with basis $\{e_1,e_2\}$.. we consider dual basis $\{e^*_1,e^*_2\}$ where $e^*_i (e_j)=\delta_{ij}$..  Now we have to consider map $T(v_1,v_2,v_3)=e^*_1(v_1)e^*_2(v_2)e^*_1(v_3)-e^*_2(v_1)e^*_1(v_2)e^*_1(v_3)$ Is this what you are referring to? for $v_1=ae_1+be_2,v_2=ce_1+de_2,v_3=me_1+ne_2$ we have $T(v_1,v_2,v_3)=(ad-bc)m$

Comment: Yes, that's what it is for $k=3$.

Comment: @darijgrinberg  : It took so much time for me to compute $Alt(T)$ and see that is is actually $0$ and see that it is not symmetric... How did you come up with such example... Please make it as an answer so that i can accept.. for $k$ tensor do i have to compute everything explicitly or is there any theory which says something of this kind have alt 0 and it is not symmetric

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is nice characterisation of tensors which $Alt(T)=0.$

> Thm. Let $V$ be a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$ (without any additional assumptions). Consider subspace $N^n(V)$ of $\otimes^nV$ generated by elements $v_1\otimes\dots\otimes v_n$ such that $v_i=v_j$ for at least one pair $i\neq j.$ We have that
>   $$\ker(Alt)=N^n(V).$$
>   Equivalently. For every $T\in\otimes^nV$
>   $$Alt(T)=0\iff T\in N^n(V).$$

It requires some work, but you can find it in Greub's Multilinear Algebra.

---

**EDIT** Explicit example

Consider space $V=(\mathbb{R}^2)^*.$ Then $3-$tensors in $V$ can be treated as multilinear maps
$$T:\mathbb{R}^2\times\mathbb{R}^2\times\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}.$$
Set $T$ by formula
$$T((a,b),(c,d),(e,f))=ace+bde-acf-bdf.$$
Multilinear: easy to verify.

Symmetric: Nope
$$T((1,1),(1,1),(1,0))=2\neq 0=T((1,0),(1,1),(1,1))$$

$Alt(T)=0.$ Yes. See first that $$T((a,b),(c,d),(e,f))=T((c,d),(a,b),(e,f))$$
(this is the main idea, compare with the thm. in quotation above). In fact

$$T((a,b),(c,d),(e,f))=ace+bde-acf-bdf=cae+dbe-caf-dbf=T((c,d),(a,b),(e,f)).$$
Now $Atl(T)$ has $6$ elements. To permutation $\sigma=id$ corresponds $\gamma=(12),$ such that $$T^\sigma=T^\gamma\hspace{5pt}\text{and}\hspace{5pt}sgn(\sigma)=-sgn(\gamma).$$ Similarly to $\sigma=(13)$ you have $\gamma=(123)$ and to $\sigma=(23)$ you have $\gamma=(132).$ Hence the whole sum $Alt(T)$ cancels out.

Comment: +1... I have done similar type of example by help of http://math.stackexchange.com/users/586/darij-grinberg .. I want to know how did you think about this examples...

Comment: I made the example in such way to be commutative in first and second argument, but **not** commutative in first and third argument (as a result not commutative in second and third). Just try to read the theorem above, mabe see the proof. By the characteristic nature of theorem ($\iff$) it contains all information you want.

Comment: Thank you... I will read that theorem... :)

Comment: I am reading it at this very moment :D

Comment: I am so glad that you are doing that :D